# How to install extension from Magento 2 official marketplace

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Can't find out the right way to install this extension.

[example of the extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-ukrainian-ukraine-language-pack.html)

Can't find in System > Integrations "Magento Connect Manager". What is the right way to install this and similar extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

provided example is of Magento1.x ( Magento Connect was used )

and you are asking for Magento2,x

https://marketplace.magento.com/extensions.html is the URL for Magento2's Extension

here you need to purchase the extension and after that you will have a download link in your account on sales order history

you need to login in magento admin (System -> Web Setup Wizard :: Component Manager) and login using public & private access key from your magento account.

than after you can sync your purchases into magento installation

or else

you can download and install it manually via command line

for command line installation you need to follow these steps

```
1) Upload new module to app/code/

2) php bin/magento module:enable EmizenTech_NewModule

3) php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

make sure to change namespace of the Module

Comment: Thanks, we'll also provide the `composer require` method in the documentation soon. The trick to that is finding the extension's Composer name, which is currently only in the SKU on the invoice.

Comment: In what directory should the command `php bin/magento module:enable EmizenTech_NewModule` be run?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir you can run the command from the root directory of Magento make sure you find the bin folder there as well.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir make sure to change namespace of the Module

I put the dummy module name so you can add your module name.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download the complete extension

2.Put the extension in the folder app/code/

3.Enable the module using the command: `php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Modulename`

4.Run a setup upgrade command to update the database: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: After `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I get the message `Please re-run Magento compile command` in Magento 2.1.7. What shall I do?

Comment: I did run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` an the browser  
shows this error: "There has been an error processing your request". In the frontend only .